# Remote Linux system via Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, fedora, desktop, remote

I have a dual boot with Windows 7 and Fedora. Though I can log into both without any problems, I am trying to log in to the Linux account via the Windows account. Is that possible?

Or, is it possible to access my university's Linux server via telnet at home? I tried and got the error `could not connect to port 23`. Also, since most of my mail accounts are on Windows, the passwords to which I have forgotten, I would prefer working on a 'remote' connection.

Comment: Try ssh instead of telnet to your university's server.

Comment: Get a connection timed out error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is tricky - you might be able to mount the fedora install as a vm.
If its just file access from the fedora install, and you arn't using LVM you can use a ext or other filesystem driver - [here's the ext driver](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) I've used in the past, but there's probably other options

For the latter, you need to use ssh rather than telnet - telnet is insecure. putty is the usual ssh client people use but there's other options

Comment: I get a connection timed out message.

Comment: check with the university then, if they don't support ssh, there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is "Dual Boot" then no, you can not connect to one operating system via the other as only one is running at any one time.

It might be possible to run Linux in Virtual Box, or VMWare under Windows. The otherway round might be possible but you are more likely to get driver problems from Windows than from Linux.

Be warned running a "natively installed" operating system (i.e. one that was installed directly on the machine) under a virtualization system is not recommended by most virtualization vendors (It can work, but they won't support you if it breaks).